# How to treat OOME exception, if increasing the size of heap doesnt work?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

im trying to draw vertical and horizontal lines between randomly clicked Points on a grid and given Points from a list of Points. My newbie style coding seems to be taking its toll on the app which crushes after i click a random point on the grid. then it throws the following OOME. Sofar i've tried increasing the heapsize. That didnt help at all.. 
any ideas??
here is the code snippet, that is causing it.i've sofar only written code for the case of a click event to the east of  a point from the list

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    boolean crossingLines = false;
    Line l;
    Point p = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
    for (int i = 0; i < pointList.size(); i++) {
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(pointList.get(i).x
                * GAPBETWEENPOINTS
                + GAP
                - TOLERANCE, pointList.y
                * GAPBETWEENPOINTS
            + GAP
                - TOLERANCE,TOLERANCE * 2,
                CLICKTOLERANCE * 2);
        if (rec.contains(p)) {
            if (clickedEast(p, pointList.get(i)) == true) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < pointList.size(); j++) {
                    if (pointList.get(j).y
                            * GAPBETWEENPOINTS
                            + GAP == pointList.get(i).y
                                    * GAPBETWEENPOINTS
                                    + GAP
                            && pointList.get(j).x
                            * GAPBETWEENPOINTS
                            + GAP > pointList.get(i).x
                            * GAPBETWEENPOINTS
                            + GAP) {
                        l = new Line(pointList.get(i),
                                pointList.get(j));
                        if (!lineList.contains(b)) {

                            for (int k = 0; k < lineList.size(); k++) {
                                if (lineList.get(k).getHorizontal() == false) {
                                    if (pointList.get(i).x
                                            * GAPBETWEENPOINTS
                                            + GAP < lineList
                                            .get(k).getStartPoint().x
                                            && lineList.get(k)
                                                    .getStartPoint().x < pointList.get(j).x
                                                    * GAPBETWEENPOINTS
                                                    + GAP
                                            && lineList.get(k)
                                                    .getStartPoint().y < pointList.get(i)).y
                                                    * GAPBETWEENPOINTS
                                                    + GAP
                                            && pointList.get(k).y
                                            * GAPBETWEENPOINTS
                                            + GAP < lineList
                                                    .get(k).getEndPoint().y) {
                                        crossinglines = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (crossingLines == false) {
                                    lineList.add(b);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        validate();
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java 
heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2245)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2219)
at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:242)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:216)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:208)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:440)
at GUIs.GameField.mouseClicked(GameField.java:326)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6519)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.
java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.
java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.
java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
```

Comment: Could you show us some code that causes the error? E.g. what happens in `GUIs.GameField.mouseClicked()`

Comment: Could have many reasons. Maybe you have a logical error and trying to create a veeery big `ArrayList` that you do not want to create. Maybe you just wrote inefficient code. We really need some of your code that is related to the exception.

Comment: `My newbie style coding` - without seeing this it is hard to help.

Comment: alrite alrite :-) code is coming. i need to adjust it a bit so that your eyes won't hurt while trying to read :)

Comment: Could you also avoid naming variables like `Line l;` as the `l` looks like an "ell", an "aye", and a "one" - it's very hard to read, as are all the one-letter variable names. You can also avoid expressions like `lineList.get(k).getHorizontal() == false` because the result of `getHorizontal()` is obviously already `boolean`, so you can use it directly. Finally, please use rational indentation and line breaks.

Comment: Because of the layout of your code example, it's hard to be sure what is going on, but note that you change the contents and size of `lineList` (don't include implementation in variable names) within the loop through `lineList`. It could be that you are increasing your list size without bound. Also, increasing heap size is almost always the wrong way to fix an OOME. You're out of memory for a reason - giving it more memory doesn't fix that reason, only makes it take longer to use it all.

Comment: If `crossingLines == false`, you're potentially adding a lot of stuff into `lineList`, because `lineList.add()` is within the loop over `lineList` itself. So it seems that `crossingLines` never evaluates to `true` and the list keeps expanding until you run out of memory.

Comment: OOME occurs when you create many objects. Thus your issue will be to do with a "new" statement being called within a loop. Add a system.out after each creation of an object and you'll pretty quickly find out which one is the issue.

Comment: Hey Mick! thx a lot! yours is my preferred answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the innermost loop within `GameField.mouseClicked()`. When `crossingLines` evaluates to `false`, you're potentially adding a lot of items into `lineList`, because `lineList.add()` is within the loop over `lineList` itself. So it seems that `crossingLines` currently never evaluates to `true` and the list keeps expanding until you run out of memory.

To fix the problem, you should somehow make sure that `lineList.add()` doesn't get called continuously. Additionally, I would suggest that you reconsider the structure of `mouseClicked()`. Currently, you have three (!) nested for-loops in the method and you're also calling `repaint()` within the middle loop, which might cause some unnecessary flickering, depending on the size of `pointList`.